# Failed to install flutter fire_cli

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, dart

Hi i am trying to install flutter fire_cli on my mac using the command dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli, but i am getting this error:

```
Building package executables... (1.8s)
Built flutterfire_cli:flutterfire.
Rename failed, path = '/Users/******/.pub-cache/_temp/dirV5KyGb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I havent been able to find a solution, I have succesfully logged into firebase on vscode project so this command should work.